# How to set JScrollPane to invisible?

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, visibility, jtabbedpane

I have a `JScrollPane` that seats inside of a `JTabbedPane` and I want to set it to invisible when a non admin user is using the program.

I have tried to use the method `setVisible(false`) but it doesn't work. If I use the same method such as `JTabbedPane.setVisible(false)`, it will hide the `JTabbedPane` but I don't want to hide the entire `JTabbedPane` I only need to hide few panels in it.

Any ideas on how to get this done?

Comment: Why  not simply remove that JScrollPane from its parent?

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`CardLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html) as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5786005/418556).  One card would be the blank panel, the other the scroll-pane.

Comment: This is already part of a CardLayout. The jTabbedPane seats on the first card and it contains many jScrollPanes. Why can I not simply hide the jScrollPanes that I don't want to display?

Comment: *"This is already part of a CardLayout."*  For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example). *"Why can I not simply.."*  I'll answer further questions as soon as I see that MCVE.